# Put results of itertools in one single list

Tags: python, list, python-itertools, cartesian-product

I've this code, and i'm trying to put all results of itertools in one single list 
: `l = ['00','01','02','03'..]` , instead of that i'm getting a list on every single line `['0', '0']  ['0', '1'] ['0', '2'] ['0', '3']`

```
import itertools

for r in itertools.product('0123456789', repeat=2):
    print list(r)
```

Comment: Why do you need `itertools` for this?

Comment: `list('0123456789')`?

Comment: Not sure why you want to use itertools, but here is an overengineered way to do so:  `[el for r in itertools.product('0123456789', repeat=1) for el in r]`

Comment: thanks, but in the case of repeat='2' it does not seem to return what i'm expecting which is : l = ['00', '01', '02', '03' . . . ]

Comment: @aliouawalid That is a requirement you should specify in the question. We cannot guess which part of your code is actually different. As written , `list('0123456789')` would answer your question. But I guessed you probably meant something else which you were not telling us, which is why I did not post that as an answer.

Comment: @Graipher yes you're right, i should have provided more details about the actual using of my code, i'll take that as a note, thanks anyway.

Comment: @Olivier allright, check my updates.

Comment: @alioua walid Thank you, that is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `itertools` you can do this:

```
from itertools import product

list(map(''.join, product('0123456789', repeat=2)))

# ['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', ...]
```

Comment: yes but in the case of repeat=2, i want it to return l = ['00' '01' '02' '03'...]

Answer (score 0):

Above code each and every iteration you are creating a list. To take the elements to one list create an empty list append items to list in each array. Actually you don't need `itertool` for this...

```
strng =  '0123456789'
num = []
for r in strng :
    num.append(r)

print(num)
```

But if you really want to use `itertools`, you can use this.

```
import itertools as iter
num = []
for r in iter.chain('0123456789') :
    num.append(r)

print(num)
```

Comment: you don't have to initialize an empty list and append, just do list(iter.chain(iterable))